# A decision problem of an inverse problem in finite group theory

Tags: finite-groups, computability-theory, computational-group-theory

A finite group $G$ is called integral if there is a finite group $H$ such that $G\cong H'$.
In Araujo, Cameron, Casolo, Matucci's paper, [integrals of groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10179), they tried to solve a problem as following:
*Given a finite group $G$, can we determine whether $G$ is integral?*

There are many similar problems. For example, given a finite group $G$, determine whether there is a finite group $H$ such that $G\cong \Phi(H)$ (or $G\cong H/Z(H)$, etc.). Araujo et al. call those problem "inverse problem in finite group theory".

My question is, **for a certain inverse problem, whether we can prove or disprove the existence of an algorithm which outputs the answer to the problem in finite time**.

For example, can we prove or disprove there is an algorithm which can output "The group $G$ is integral" in finite time if we input an integral group $G$ and output "The group $G$ is non-integral" in finite time if we input a non-integral group $G$? I'm particularly interested in the problem of determining whether a finite group is integral.
**Can we know the existence of an algorithm which can answer the integral group problem?**
I know we might need to construct an algorithm to prove the existence of algorithm if there is an algorithm for the integral group problem. But **how to prove the non-existence of algorithm if there is no such an algorithm?**

In Eick's [paper](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/PL00004286), she gave a positive answer to the problem of determining whether there is a group $H$ such that $G\cong \Phi(H)$. She proved that $G\cong \Phi(H)$ for some $H$ if and only if $Inn(G) ≤ \Phi(Aut(G))$.

---

Some idea: Define a *characteristic functor* $F$ a functor sending a finite group $G$ to a characteristic subgroup of $G$ such that for any isomorphism $\sigma:G\rightarrow H$, $F(G^\sigma)=(F(G))^\sigma$. Now, we define a characteristic functor as following:
$$\chi(G)=\left\{\begin{aligned}&G,\mbox{ if $G$ is integral}\\
&1,\mbox{ otherwise}\end{aligned}\right.$$
Then it can be seen the problem is decidable if and only if $\chi$ is computable hence we might solve this problem if we know enough properties of computable characteristic functor.

For example, given two characteristic functors $F_1$ and $F_2$, their composition $F_1F_2(G):=F_1(F_2(G))$ is also a characteristic functor. Moreover, if both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are computable, $F_1F_2$ is also computable. If we can find some `initial' characteristic functors and operations on characteristic functors which preserving computability and prove they can generate all computable characteristic functors, we then derive a good description about computable characteristic functors.

Comment: Surely the term for such a group should be "integrable"?  The abstract of the paper you link gives an upper bound on the necessary size of the integral $H$.  So for the case of integrable groups, an algorithm exists by bounded search.  Just examine all groups up to the necessary size.

Comment: @DanTuretsky Yes. I think they gave the upper bounds for all finite abelian groups but it seems that they didn't give any upper bounds for non-abelian finite groups so it might not work.